# arduino connection to mysql fails

Tags: arduino-uno

I tried to connect xampp/mysql to arduino but connection fails.
mysql is running on port 3306.
I searched a lot on the internet but could not understand where is the problem!
Would you please help me...

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>

byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };

IPAddress server_addr(127,0,0,1);  // IP of the MySQL *server* here
char user[] = "root";              // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "";        // MySQL user login password

EthernetClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial); // wait for serial port to connect
  Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);
  Serial.println("Connecting...");
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password)) {
    delay(1000);
     Serial.println("Connection stablished.");
    // You would add your code here to run a query once on startup.
  }
  else
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  conn.close();
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: you forgot to put in the server IP ... 127.0.0.1 is not a network IP

Comment: I also try my pc IP but didn't work . Did you mean that?

Comment: i meant only what i said, that the IP you provided is invalid .... you said nothing about the MySQL server, so no comment can be made about the server

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand it. So which IP should I set to work?

Comment: you need to use the IP of the MySQL server ... you also have to make sure that the server can be reached .... use another computer to verify that .... the setup and verification of the MySQL server is not related to the Arduino, so don't ask about it here

Comment: how can I understand what is my MYSQL IP ? Is it different from my pc IP?